# SMTP relay restriction radio buttons disabled

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, smtp

I might just be doing something really dumb, but the two radio button options for my SMTP server relay restrictions are disabled and I have no idea why. I've included a screenshot below to help illustrate. I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2. Thanks in advance for any help!

*EDIT:* I might need to mention that I'm logging into the box through a remote desktop connection for Mac. Thanks again for taking the time to read!

[image: relay restriction radio buttons disabled screenshot]

Comment: Run as Administrator?

Comment: Nope, same thing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solve this problem, exactly same problem. So I sign up an account to reply this post.

The problem is on the "Remote desktop connection for Mac".
Try to use CoRD to connect to your server's desktop, you'll get your radio buttons back.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't tell you how to render the missing buttons, I can assure you that the controls are still on that window form.

If the window is active it is possible to tab and cycle to each element in this form.  When you believe that you have selected one of the radio buttons' labels, use the arrow keys.  The visual cues will be obvious once you see them.

I just found this bug myself.  *I was also using the OSX remote desktop connection to a Windows 2008 R2 server.*  Though I thought that the other fields had been disabled for some unknown reason.  Ha!

Comment: Very interesting...thanks for the help! I'll give it a shot when I next boot up the virtual box and hopefully bring some feedback! :)